# Escaping apostrophes in Android Studio's XML files?

Tags: android-studio

So I have this line in a XML file in Android Studio:

```
<string name="btn_inventaire_intervention">Inventaire d'intervention</string>
```

When I try to compile, it says that I need to escape the "'" with a "\". So, I change the line above to:

```
<string name="btn_inventaire_intervention">Inventaire d\'intervention</string>
```

And then, as I compile, Android Studio removes the "\" and gives me the first error again. What's the solution to that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out I was inadvertently changing the "values.xml" file which is regenerated with each compile. The error was originally into another file (whose content was copied into "values.xml").

Comment: Nevertheless it's a bug in AS, even in version 2.2, because when I click on the compile error results, it opens the xml file inside the build folder and not the original xml.

Answer (score -2):

Just put everything with quotes:

```
<string name="btn_inventaire_intervention">"Inventaire d'intervention"</string>
```